# How to update Evolution email client

Tags: evolution

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, which comes with Evolution 3.10. Sadly the 3.10 version is far too buggy to be used. How can I update to a newer version? Or is that is not possible, downgrade to an earlier one.

Each and every repository I have tried offers this very same version 3.10.